# Change text against radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load some text from json response against a radio button 
While the text is getting rendered - the radio button disappears

Here is my code in Jquery

```
$('#lblFirstOption').text(val["answerOne"]);
```

My HTML is like this :

```
<label class="block" id="lblFirstOption" for = "sizeSmall"> 
      <input type = "radio"
             name = "radSize"
             id = "sizeSmall"
             value = "small"
             />

      small</label>
```

any ideas please ?

Comment: You should put label inside of the input tag

Comment: @irvgk what? You can't put anything inside `input`. It is fine as OP hasa it.

Comment: @putvande you can put.. but its suggestible to put inside.. so that you can access it easily if necessary

Comment: Maybe we are talking about 2 different things here. Are you talking about `<input attributes....><label>text</label></input>`?

Comment: Don't put the damn label inside the `input` - `input` does not have any children.

Comment: I would move the input outside the label as you have the `for` attribute on the label anyway so it doesn't really need to be inside it

Comment: @irvgk I think you should read this: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-input-element - Content model: empty - means it's not allowed to have children

Comment: @Pete You mean to say these all are wrong? http://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: @irvgk do you want to search the source of that page and tell me where you have found an `input` with an element inside it.  If they are doing it then yes, it is wrong.  Why don't you try this http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input and see if it is valid, by all means you can carry on doing it but you will be ranked down on search engines for having invalid html - all browsers will do is ignore the closing input tag

Comment: @Pete thanks for the information.. I didn't know for input tag I never used it but I used it for buttons.. I thought it will apply for the same to buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited answer:

The jQuery function `text()` overwrites the **whole** content of the label, that's why the radio button also gets overwritten. Instead of usin*g the jQuery function `text()` I recommend using the DOM node property `nextSibling` to get the text node after the radio input and edit its value using `nodeValue``

```
$('input')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = "The quick brown fox..."
```

Explanation:
`$('input')[0]` picks the first result of `$('input')`, which is a DOM node, so that we can edit the property `nodeValue` of its property `nextSibling`.

I've set up a little [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jdvndsr6/) to demonstrate how it works.

Comment: if you use after, it wouldn't change the label text, just add to it

Comment: Yeah, you've got a point there… if he just wants to change the text once he could omit the plain text inside the label. Anyway, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @ivogel - using after is simply appending to existing text as Pete pointed out

Comment: Updated my answer, now everything should be fine.

Comment: @Ivogel - you are the man !!! tres excellente ! - super - thanks a ton :) - I am sorry I would like to upvote but I dont have the necessary 15 rep as yet :(

Answer (score 0):

You could take the input out of the label. It will still work as you have the for attribute set. Not sure if this would upset styling.

```
<label class="block" id="lblFirstOption" for = "sizeSmall">small</label>
<input type = "radio" name = "radSize" id = "sizeSmall" value = "small" />
```